# Why NegativeBinomialP gives different coefficients compared to R?

Tags: python, r, statsmodels

I am getting little difficulty to repeat the following R exercise into python to achive the same results. What am I missing?

R exercise
https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/negative-binomial-regression/

data link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mz4stp72eco3rfq/sampleNBdata2.dat?dl=0

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import statsmodels.distributions.discrete as distr
from statsmodels.discrete.discrete_model import NegativeBinomialP, NegativeBinomial, Poisson, GeneralizedPoisson
from statsmodels.discrete.count_model import (ZeroInflatedNegativeBinomialP, ZeroInflatedPoisson,
                                              ZeroInflatedGeneralizedPoisson)
import statsmodels.discrete._diagnostics_count as dia

import statsmodels.api as sm


f=open('sampleNBdata2.dat')
id=[]
gender=[]
math=[]
daysabs=[]
prog=[]
x=[]
f.readline()
d={}
d['Academic']=1
d['Vocational']=2
d['General']=3

for line in f:
    l=line.split(',')
    id.append(l[1])
    gender.append(l[2])
    math.append(l[3]) #independent
    daysabs.append(int(l[4])) #dependent y
    prog.append(l[5]) #independent
    #x.append([int(l[3]),d[l[5]], ] )
    x.append([int(l[3]),int(l[5]), ] )

print(x,daysabs)
endog=np.array(daysabs)
exog=np.array(x)


print("endog",endog.shape)
print("exog",exog.shape)



#model_nb = NegativeBinomial(endog, exog, loglike_method='nb2')
model_nb = NegativeBinomialP(endog, exog, p=2)

res_nb = model_nb.fit(method='bfgs', maxiter=5000, maxfun=5000)

print(endog)
print(exog)
print(res_nb.summary())
```

Python output
[image]
R output
[image]

Comment: looks like you did not add an intercept to the exog in statsmodels. It is NOT added automatically except when using formulas. And `prog` is categorical in R, while you convert it to numeric, AFAICS. Use pandas and formulas, then the default behavior is similar to R.

Answer (score 0):

Following codes are reproducing the result of R almost with similar coefficients.

```
df=pd.read_csv('sampleNBdata.dat')
data=pd.concat((df,pd.get_dummies(df['prog'],drop_first=False)),axis=1)
endog=data['daysabs']
data['intercept'] = 1
exog=data.drop(['prog','daysabs','id','gender','Unnamed: 0','General'],axis=1)
model_nb = NegativeBinomialP(endog, exog, p=2)
res_nb = model_nb.fit(method='bfgs', maxiter=5000, maxfun=5000)
print(res_nb.summary())
```

[image]